# How to condense a matrix for McNemar sig testing using R?

Tags: r, statistical-test

I have survey data I am looking to test for significance, specifically between two questions (a2 and a3). The sample between the two questions is non mutually exclusive so I am hoping to apply the mcnemar test. The response matrix is:

[image]

I need to test for significance between those who selected a in a3 vs those who selected a in a2, then those who selected b in a3 vs those who selected b in a2 etc. Right now I am manually creating 2x2 matrices and using mcnemar.test(matrix), for example the 2x2 matrix for e vs e is

[image]

But my question is is there a way to create a loop or some process to more efficiently create these matrices?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
mat <- matrix(c(16, 7, 3, 0, 23, 1, 9, 1, 0, 22, 3, 1, 11, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 21, 7, 9, 1, 67), 
              ncol = 5, 
              dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                              c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))

mat2 <- matrix(c(sum(mat[1:4,1:4]), sum(mat[5,1:4]), 
                 sum(mat[1:4,5]), mat[5,5]),
               ncol = 2,
               dimnames = list(c("a-d", "e"), c("a-d", "e")))

mat2
#>     a-d  e
#> a-d  52 38
#> e    68 67
```

Or to generalize to any square matrix NxN (N > 1)

```
to_2x2 <- function(mat) {
  # assume square matrix
  stopifnot(nrow(mat) == ncol(mat))
  n <- nrow(mat)
  stopifnot(n > 1)
  
  # extra processing for dimnames omitted
  
  matrix(c(sum(mat[1:(n-1),1:(n-1)]), 
           sum(mat[n,1:(n-1)]), 
           sum(mat[1:(n-1),n]), 
           mat[n,n]), ncol = 2)
}

to_2x2(mat)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   52   38
#> [2,]   68   67
```

---

Starting with pre-tabulated data:

```
## start with example tabulated counts
mat <- matrix(c(16, 7, 3, 0, 23, 1, 9, 1, 0, 22, 3, 1, 11, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 21, 7, 9, 1, 67), 
              ncol = 5, 
              dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                              c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))

## generate pre-tabulated data
a2 <- character(0)
a3 <- character(0)
for (i in seq.int(nrow(mat))) {
  for (j in seq.int(ncol(mat))) {
    a2 <- c(a2, rep(rownames(mat)[i], mat[i,j]))
    a3 <- c(a3, rep(rownames(mat)[j], mat[i,j]))
  }
}

pretab_dat <- data.frame(a2 = a2, a3 = a3)

## derive 2x2 tabulations
labels = unique(c(pretab_dat$a2, pretab_dat$a3))
tabs_2x2 = list()

for (i in seq_along(labels)) {
  others <- setdiff(labels, labels[i])  # all other labels except current
  others_name <- paste(others, collapse = "|")
  
  # re-label orig data
  temp <- transform(pretab_dat,
                    a2 = ifelse(a2 %in% others, others_name, a2),
                    a3 = ifelse(a3 %in% others, others_name, a3))
  
  # tabulate re-labeled data
  tabs_2x2[[i]] <- xtabs(~ a2 + a3, data = temp)
}

tabs_2x2
#> [[1]]
#>          a3
#> a2          a b|c|d|e
#>   a        16      25
#>   b|c|d|e  33     151
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>          a3
#> a2        a|c|d|e   b
#>   a|c|d|e     177  24
#>   b            15   9
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>          a3
#> a2        a|b|d|e   c
#>   a|b|d|e     175  26
#>   c            13  11
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>          a3
#> a2        a|b|c|e   d
#>   a|b|c|e     223   1
#>   d             1   0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>          a3
#> a2        a|b|c|d  e
#>   a|b|c|d      52 38
#>   e            68 67
```

Comment: So setting up one matrix isn't an issue, I am using: test.matrix <- as.matrix(xtabs(~ a1a2 + a1a3, Stat.sub)) where Stat.sub is a table of a1a2 and a1a3 responses (output gives me my response matrix) . The issue is creating all the 2x2 matrices quickly / automatically

Comment: Your original question started with the tabulated data, so that's where I started. If you start with pre-tabulated data then one approach is to re-label the values before tabulating. I added a script doing that above.